# Assign number to variable in perl subroutine [assign returned list to variables]

Tags: perl

I am trying to call a multiple variable from a subroutine but when i try to print, it just print only one variable.

In python the script will be f=mode()[0] and b=mode()[1] and it works.

subroutinefile a.pl

```
sub mode() {
    my ($f, $b);
    $f=41;
    $b=2;
    return ($f,$b);
 }
```

And another file that calls the a.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
require 'a.pl';
my ($f,$b);
$f= mode(0);
$b= mode(1);
print "$f\n";
print "$b\n";
```

The problem is it only prints 2 for both f and b.

Comment: @Shawn no; in scalar context, there is no list.  the comma operator in `return ($f, $b)` is in scalar context when the sub call has scalar context, and it discards its left operand, leaving the sub just returning `$b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the mismatch between the definition of the subroutine (no parameters) and the way you are trying to call it (one argument).

Change those calls to this and it works:

```
$f= (mode())[0];
$b= (mode())[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have passed arguments **to** subroutine: `$f = mode(0); $b = mode(1);`.

Try the following:

```
my ($f,$b) = mode();
```

Your subroutine returns a fixed length list. You may assign values in the list to your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Think there is a syntactical difference between getting an array index FROM the return set versus sending an argument; function(xxx) sends the argument, (function()[])is using an array slice of the return.